# HP EliteBook 840 G6 Brightnees Issue

Tags: windows-10, brightness, function-keys, hp-elitebook

Today I noticed that the brightness control bar in the action center is not adjusting the brightness. I updated all the available device updates and windows update, nothing fixed it. However the laptop keyboard Function keys (F3 & F4) do make the change with showing this pop up indicator:
[brightness hot key (F3) on the laptop keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp2mf.png)

but when I use the same keys on my secondary keyboard it changes has this pupup:
[brightness hot key (F3) on the secondary keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tXby.png), it doesn't have the little laptop icon on top.

So it seems the brightness is still functional but somehow it is not accessible through the action center bar.
Any ideas how to fix it so both the hotkeys and the bar do the same thing (adjsuting the brightness)?

My laptop is HP EliteBook 840 G6 with all the latest updates of the devices and the Windows OS.

Comment: Update the machine BIOS and power drivers. Then run DISM and SFC , restart and test.  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: the BIOS update alone fixed it :)  Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the update. Experience has taught me that driver updates are a good first step.  I hope you will acknowledge my answer.

Comment: Yes that is true but I didn't think that BIOS affects device drivers. I up voted your answer but it says that my vote is recorded but do not change the public displayed score :( because my reputation is one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of issue, Driver updates are always important.

Update the machine BIOS and power drivers.

Another step, if necessary is to run DISM and SFC , restart and test.

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.